# Hibernate CriteriaQuery How to Find list of integer having two conditions

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I got two entity class one:

```
@Table(name = "package")
public class Package {


    @Id
    @Column(name = "package_id", insertable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long packageId;

    @Column(name = "timestamp", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date timestamp;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "queue_id",foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name = "package_queue_id_fk"))
    private Queue Queue;

@Column(name = "file_number", nullable = true)
private Integer fileNumber;
```

And

```
@Table(name = "queue")
public class Queue {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "queue_id", insertable = false, nullable = false)
    private Integer queue;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = true)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "Queue", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "package_id")
    private Set<Package> packages;
```

And I would like to find List of fileNumbers depending on package.name and package.queue.queue_id

So currently I got only one condition (name) and it looks like this:

```
public List<Integer> getAllFileNumbers(String fileName, Integer queueId) {

    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Integer> query = cb.createQuery(Integer.class);

    Root<Package> package = query.from(package.class);
    query.select(package.get("fileNumber")).where(cb.equal(package.get("name"), fileName));

    return em.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```

Anyone could help me add another one, on top of thet remamber that the value need to be from another entity.

Edit:

So after @Leviand hint I did it like this:

```
        Predicate filenamePred= cb.equal(package.get("name"), fileName);
        Predicate queueIdPred = cb.equal(package.get("queue_id"), queueId);

        query.select(package.get("fileNumber")).where(cb.and(filenamePred, queueIdPred ));
```

I got error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [queue_id] on this ManagedType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the two predicates ( you can ofc write it all inline, I'm splitting so it's clearer) in a `or` condition, for example:

```
Predicate filename= cb.equal(package.get("name"), fileName);
Predicate queueId = cb.equal(package.get("queue"), queueId);

//then use them in a or condition
query.select(root).where(cb.and(filename, queueId ));
```

Comment: So i did like you wrote, but it seems likie application is unable to locate queue_id. I will edit my question post.

Comment: @Suule I've used the column name that you provided in your example, check if that's correct :)

Comment: But shouldnt I use it like Queue.queue? Because I need to find package which has queue wuth specific id, and id of queue I am storing in  Queue class.

Comment: @Suule I've seen I've writed the column name and not the field name, I've edited my question, try it now

Comment: Yes exactly, I've misstyped that! My bad, sorry :)

Comment: And I think in this answer there should be cb.and instead of cb.or. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

`queue_id` is the name of the column. You have to use the name of the field, which is `Queue`, and you have to get it's id field (`queue`) to compare.

This can be made easier and more type-safe if you use the metamodel-generator.